# httpd.exe - entry point not found error

Tags: apache

I am installing wamp server in my win8 pc but error occupying. this error is showing in "httpd.exe - entry point not found" small window.

In this window -

> "the procedure entry point free could not be located in the dynamic
>   link library
>
> c:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.23\bin\libapriconv-1.dll"

please anyone help me. how to fix this error.

[image]

Comment: ever find whats wrong?